# Raise JSON decode Error Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, django

I am creating a website using Django . 
Below is my code:

views.py:

```
for i in range(0,len(userdata)):
        json_hall = requests.get(
            "https://www.onebookingsystem.com/API/Admin/booking_list_id.php?id=%s" % userdata[i]['bookid'])
        r = json_hall.json()
        hall_data = json.loads(json_hall.text)
        id_data[i]['bookid'] = hall_data[0]['bookid']
```

When i run i am getting the error like this.

```
File "D:\KarthikWorkSpace\Projects\Python\obs_admin\Application\obs_app\views.py", line 1968, in bookings_owner
hall_data = json.loads(json_hall.text)

raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: json_hall.json() will give json already dont use json.loads again

Comment: I have tried not using json.loads, but still it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This usually means that the string you're trying to decode is empty, eg:

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Please, make sure the request you are sending is correct.

You could print or inspect `response.text` to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

When using `requests`, the `.json()` method on a response object already gives you a Python object (decoded from the literal response)

You don't need to parse again the data with `json.loads`. By the way, here's a more Pythonic way to iterate over your data:

```
for (idx, user) in enumerate(userdata):
    response = requests.get(
            "https://www.onebookingsystem.com/API/Admin/booking_list_id.php?id=%s" % user['bookid'])
    hall_data = response.json()
    id_data[idx]['bookid'] = hall_data[0]['bookid']
```

Comment: i tried not parsing with json.loads , but the error still remains.